# Tree with 3 children

Tags: c++, data-structures

this is the data structure type question i have a problem with the tree i want to take input from user say its name. "DAN" now i want to make a tree for that with root node having three children.
i have a tree having three children.

how i will implement it with linked list. because in binary tree linked list has two children.

but here i have three. simple is that i have a root node having three children

```
                root
                / | \
               /  |  \
             ch1 ch2  ch3
```

Comment: "because in binary tree linked list has two children." Sounds about as sensible as: "because my dog is dreaming of angry rainbows."

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you create a structure with three children pointers:

```
struct TreeNode
{
    int data;
    TreeNode *children[3];
};
```

Alternatively, you can turn the children into a linked list, so that any given node only has a direct pointer to its first child as well as its first sibling:

```
struct TreeNode
{
    int data;
    TreeNode *firstChild;
    TreeNode *nextSibling;
};

// To iterate through the children of a node:
TreeNode *child = root->firstChild;
while (child != NULL)
{
    // Do stuff with child
    ...
    child = child->nextSibling;
}
```

This extends more easily to any number of children, but it has higher performance penalties when accessing data.  So if you know that each node will have at most 3 children, it's better to use a fixed array of child pointers to improve access times and improve cache locality.

Comment: It does not compile. You need `struct TreeNode` (as in the previous edit

Comment: can you define it in the form of TEMPLATE please. in C++ not in C

Comment: @Artemis - Have you heard of STL. Very handy - Work done for you. Unless it is homework - what you should do for yourself.

Comment: its not a home work just implementing it via vectors but can't